# php code to display images from directory not working

Tags: php, image

i have this code to display images, where each user has his own, i'll comment it to save your time

```
    <?php
session_start();
$name=$_SESSION['valid_user']; //saved current username in variable
$loc="./uploads/";             //location of image directory
$path=$loc.$name;              //current user's folder to save his images 
echo $path."<br>";             //i used this to make sure the path is ok, only for testing

if(is_dir($path))              //if directory exists, show it exists,otherwise show it
{                              //doesnt exists
    echo "<br>exists";
} 
else 
{ 
        echo "<br>not exists"; 
}
$files = glob($path."/");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)  
{
    $num = $files[$i];          //picture number
    print $num."<br />";
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="random image" height="100" width="100"/>'."<br /><br />";
}                           //shows the picture till the last one
?>
```

the output that i get is this this

```
./uploads/user_name

exists
```

but it does not show the images, even though the folder is not empty (upload script works fine).

***EDIT; solved it (low rep, cant answer my own question).***

got it. For anyone who cares, this line here

```
echo '<img src="' . $path . '/' . $files[$i] . '" <!-- etc --> />';
```

wasn't working because i added $files, which already contained the path, and it was giving input to img src as

```
/uploads/username/uploads/username
```

so that was two times the same path.Upon removing $path, and using just

```
<img src="' . $files[$i] . '"
```

did the trick. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Show your output html code from server

Comment: I don't think you can iterate through the files in that directory like that. $files should be an array, and should contain the list of files/images to be shown beforehand.

Comment: You're missing the first file in the folder (`$files[0]`)

Comment: @kirugan i have already shown the output there.

Comment: @arjan yes you are right, when i was trying that at localhost somehow it seemed to work starting from 1 only. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass a wildcard path to `glob`: `glob($path . '/*')`. You are also not printing the filename in the image source attribute:

```
echo '<img src="' . $path . '/' . $files[$i] . '" <!-- etc --> />';
```

Also, your `$num` is actually the filename, not the picture number - that is `$i`. You could really simplify that loop using the `foreach` construct:

```
foreach($files as $filename) {
  // etc
}
```

Comment: @sid0972 `foreach($files as $num => $filename)`

Comment: after adding filename ($path.$files[$i]), still its not working
it just shows blanks, but can get the image names right.

Comment: @sid0972 Do not forget the slash after the path! `$path.'/'.$files[$i]`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a pattern for using glob afaik

```
$files = glob($path."/*.*"); // all files
$files = glob($path."/*.jpg"); // all jpgs etc.pp

foreach($files as $idx => $file)
{
    $num = $idx+1; //idx starts with 0 so we add one here
    print $num."<br />";
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'/'.$file'" alt="random image" height="100" width="100"/>'."<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: yes the pattern as not set, but after adding *.* i can only see the blanks, not images, i'll check and report back.